# db2 v10 z/os native sql stored procedure called via mq v6

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-mq

I am trying to call z/os db2 v10 native sql stored procedure via the builtin mq listener

i got very close to making it work however the response message payload is always empty, even when i simply set the varchar out parameter to fixed constant string.

cn anyone shed any light on a good resource for how to configure the builtin mq listener on z/os for db2 v10?

or has anyone experienced this type of problem?

i have been using the db2 v10 infocentre and the redbook extremely pure xml.

these showed db2mq.send and recieved calls howveer i do not think you have to use those commands to be able to send and recieve data i/out of native stored procedures.